# saving a file variable for use later?

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser

I am working on a program for launching programs, and am using JFileChooser to let the user select the file, i would like the program to have the path of the last file available the next time the user starts my program, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Place the value in a properties file. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Just simply write the file's path to a textfile and every time you open that program read in that same path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a properties file which acts similarly to a hashtable. This code should be pretty accurate (needs exception handling).

```
private void save(String _url){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("url", _url);
    prop.store(new FileOutputStream("file.properties"), null);
}

private String open(){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("file.properties"));
    return prop.getProperty("url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your program is web based then stored it in session, or write in file.